# How to enable Function Result Cache

Tags: oracle, caching, oracle11g

I'm trying to use Oracle's [Function Result Cache](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm#BABFHACJ) on *11.2.0*, so I did the following test:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_test_value
  RETURN NUMBER
  RESULT_CACHE
AS
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line( 'Called' );
  RETURN 0;
END;

SELECT get_test_value FROM dual;
```

My example prints `Called` every time, though.
I also tried some other examples found online, but the cache is not used.

I tried `ALTER SYSTEM SET result_cache_max_size = 10485760;`
Still doesn't work.

I tried `ALTER SESSION SET result_cache_mode=FORCE;` (which should not be necessary) - didn't help.

`SELECT dbms_result_cache.status FROM dual;` always returns `DISABLED`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Which edition are you using?  The Cache functionality is only available in Enterprise Edition, so if you're trying this on a Standard Edition install it wouldn't work.  It's in the [Licensing Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/license.111/b28287/editions.htm#BABDJGGI).

Comment: Personal Edition may have it, but Personal Edition is Windows only and 11gR2 hasn't come out on windows yet

Comment: Ouch. Tried with Enterprise and it works like a charm :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Peter Lang - Most of Oracle's sexy new features tend to be EE only (when they aren't chargeable extras) so the Licensing Guide is a vital read.

Answer (score 0):

Im going to add this information here because i found it useful in solving my similar problem.

if you are getting a status of DISABLED or BYPASS remember

***The Result Cache memory area is located in the Shared Pool so, the value of result_cache_max_size is consumed from the Shared Pool size.***

so check the following parameters

```
show parameter shared_pool_size
show parameter result_cache_max_size
show parameter result_cache_mode
```

you can also try

```
BEGIN
    dbms_result_cache.ByPass(False);
END;
/
```

Comment: And also check if SGA_TARGET is set to zero.  See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGDBA/tune_result_cache.htm#GUID-753CE20B-ADC5-457C-8669-83250B79DD32 for all the details.